# Problem creating empty nodes

Tags: pstricks

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong. Since when I try to compile in Overleaf I get the "undefined control sequence" and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I want to generate what I show in the image. I appreciate your help.[image]

This is my try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}



\[ \frac{3}{\pnode[0.5ex, -0.5ex]{a}5} + \frac{1}{\pnode[1ex, -0.5ex]{b}10} = \frac{6}{\pnode[1ex, -0.5ex]{c}10} + \frac{1}{\pnode[1ex, -0.5ex]{d}10} = \frac{7}{10}%\
\psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, arcangle=-40, dash=3pt 2pt}
\ncarc{a}{c}\ncarc[linestyle=dashed]{b}{d}\]

\end{document}
```

What Overleaf shows me is:
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.

[image: Overleaf]

Comment: Will this work in Overleaf? I don't have LaTex downloaded.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Can_I_use_the_pstricks_package_on_Overleaf%3F

Comment: You can compile with `xelatex` without problems.